# I want to convert Object Array to Object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

Sorry... I made a misstake about example...

I want to convert Object Array to Single Object.

Before

```js
[
 {key: "A", value: "a"},
 {key: "B", value: "b"},
 {key: "C", value: "c"},
 .
 .
 .
]
```

After

```js
{
 A: "a",
 B: "b",
 C: "c"
 .
 .
 .
}
```

I try to use Object.assign(), but it doesn't work well.

Do you know any good methods for that?

Comment: @NickParsons: strangely, this dupe wasn't closed by another golden badge owner who was the author of (exactly the same) accepted answer in that thread

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov oh lol, didn't even realize. I guess the question/answer is 3 years old so they may have forgotten about their old answer...

Comment: @Jamm : you seem to be switching directions too fast, though, the latest edit of my answer returns your expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const src = [{key:"A",value:"a"},{key:"B",value:"b"},{key:"C",value:"c"}],

     result = src.reduce((acc, {key,value}) => 
      (acc[key] = value, acc), {})
      
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You coulds [spread `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const 
    data = [{ name: 'A' }, { firstname: 'Jamm' }, { age: "23" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...data);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and inside callback iterate the object to add keys and value to the accumulator object

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'A'
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jamm'
  },
  {
    age: "23"
  },
]
const newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  for (let keys in curr) {
    acc[keys] = curr[keys]

  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.prototype.reduce` to combine the individual objects into one single object:

```js
const data = [{ name: 'A' }, { firstname: 'Jamm' }, { age: '23'}];

function combineObjects(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    return { ...o,  ...acc };
  }, {});
}
console.log(combineObjects(data));
```